# Buffer I/O error on dev sda6, logical block 44, async page read

Tags: filesystems, boot, partition, kali-linux, buffer

I don't know why this happens... I was just doing my work (development) and suddenly one of my drive start lagging then I just unmount it by right click on it.

After it is still lagging, so I restart the system but system didn't open.

My configuration:
Kali Linux 2021.1
There is two main partition one is root (/dev/sda3) and my personal data partition (/dev/sda6).

```
Buffer I/O error on dev sda6, logical block 44, async page read.
```

See complete error.
[image]

This error always stay... And don't go anywhere.

**Note:** On the error screen (mid-of booting) I able to access terminal. But on ternimal I also have a error: `read only file system` I also try to fix this by `mount -o remount,rw /` but it also  throw an error called `write-protected`

Answer (score 4):

Your `sda` disk is reporting media errors, specifically within the `sda6` partition. And it looks like the root partition went read-only too, indicating that there may be further errors there too.

If your personal data is not safely backed up, start making a backup **right now**. This is exactly how a dying disk might look like.

When your data is safe, you might want to check the SMART information to evaluate the state of the disk:

```
smartctl -x /dev/sda
```

This will produce a lot of output: if you don't know how to interpret it, copy & paste it into your question here, or into a pastebin site and add a link to it into your question.

Comment: How can I backup? BTW what's the solution?

Comment: BTW I live boot and unmounted the system? Is it good idea?

Comment: Yes, live booting and then mounting the system disk partitions, and then copying all important files to some external media is a good idea. Get your important files to safety first, then it's time to see if the disk can still work or not, and if you should still trust it or not.

Comment: Even if it turns out looking okay now, I recommend replacing the hard-drive (or SSD). You do not want to lose your favourite data and days of work because you wanted to save the money.